# CSS: Background Image is sometimes missing pieces on mobile

Tags: html, css, image-size

I have searched for a couple hours on this topic, to no avail. When I view my site on mobile via Safari, sometimes pieces of the background image are missing. For instance, everything will look great, but then there will be a chunk missing in the middle. Or, perhaps instead there will be a chunk missing from the bottom. It appears to be random. Then, if I turn the phone, the missing piece fills in and even if I turn it back to portrait mode, the piece has filled in.

Any ideas as to why a section of an image won’t load? Could it be that the image is too big? Just looking for some ideas to get started with. Unfortunately, I haven’t come across this problem in my searches. Thanks.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you are having issues with. See the following article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Images should not be missing chunks.  If it is a JPEG image, there is the tiny possibility your image is being corrupted in transit.  Is the image being created dynamically?

But the most likely cause is that you have some html element over the top of the image that is opaque - and preventing the underlying image from being displayed.